# handles too many arguments, program is timing out

Tags: c, timeout

```c
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    if(argv[1] == 0)//If nothing is typed in (0), program will remind user of usage
    {
        printf("Usage: ./substitution key\n");
        return 1;
    }
    int l = strlen(argv[1]);
    int n = 0;
    char arr[] = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'};
    char arr2[] = {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z'};
    if(l != 26)//If user doesn't input exactly 26 chars, prints
        {
            printf("Key must contain 26 characters\n");
            return 1;
        }
    for(int g = 0; g < l; g++)//Loops through key and detects anything other than alphabetical chars
    {
        if(isalpha(argv[1][g]))
        {
            continue;
        }
        else{
            printf("Key must only contain alphabetical characters\n");
            return 1;
        }
    }
    while(n != l)//loops through key and looks for first repeated char. Once finished, will go to next char (n) and check that one until looped through entire key
    {
    for(int j = n + 1; j != l; j++)//detect repeat
    {
        if(argv[1][n] == argv[1][j])
        {
                printf("Key must not contain repeated characters\n");
                return 1;
        }
    }
    n++;
    }
    string p = get_string("plaintext: ");//Plain text input
    int r = strlen(p);
    int h = 0;
    printf("ciphertext: ");//answer is printed directly after this
    while(h != r) //loops through plain(h) once, goes into for loop, for loop runs through entirely, goes to next char in plain(h++), then restarts until plain is printed out one char at a time
    {
    for(int f = 0; f < l; f++)
    {
        if(p[h] == arr[f] || p[h] == arr2[f] || isupper(p[h]))
        {
            if(islower(p[h]) && p[h] == tolower(arr[f]))//prints lowercase chars
            {
                printf("%c", tolower(argv[1][f]));
                break;
            }
            if(isupper(p[h]) && p[h] == toupper(arr[f]))//prints uppercase chars
            {
                printf("%c", toupper(argv[1][f]));
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    if(isspace(p[h]) || ispunct(p[h]) || isdigit(p[h]))//prints anything in "p" (plaintext) that is not alphabetical
        {
            printf("%c", p[h]);
        }
        h++;
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

I've been looking at this and testing different inputs for hours and cannot seem to find the issue. The program is timing out because it handles too many arguments; this is the only issue. I'm assuming this is to do with one or multiple loop arguments. I'm super new to coding so it's messy, sorry; I'm sure it's something simple being overlooked.